# Set default TLS SNI vhost for Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, tls, sni

I have a CentOS 6 server with Apache (httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.x86_64). Now I configured TLS SNI using OpenSSL and that was pretty easy.

Now I have two TLS vhosts on the same ip and I want to specify which one should be the default it the client does not support TLS SNI (yes, I'm looking at you, git/hg).

Looking at the Apache docs there should be at least two ways to do this:

- set  for the default host (and *:443 for all others)
- set "SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on" for the non-default hosts.

Unfortunately neither method works for me. Can someone explain to me how to achieve the goal anyway and why the two methods above don't work as I expected?

Answer (score 2):

1st enabled will be the default one so rename the config file of the default vhost to something like `00-config_file_name` so it is the 1st loaded.

### As you (rightfully) would like something documented:

From Apache docs: [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/details.html#page-header)

> Name-based vhost
>
> If the entry corresponds to a name-based vhost the name list contains one or more vhost structures. This list contains the vhosts in the same order as the VirtualHost directives appear in the config file.
>
> The first vhost on this list (the first vhost in the config file with the specified IP address) has the highest priority and catches any request to an unknown server name or a request without a Host: header field.
>
> If the client provided a Host: header field the list is searched for a matching vhost and the first hit on a ServerName or ServerAlias is taken and the request is served from that vhost. A Host: header field can contain a port number, but Apache always matches against the real port to which the client sent the request.

So if you use only 1 config file for your vhosts, you need to order them in the file and if you include several separated files (including ../sites-enabled directory which is the way Apache2 sample site is defined) you need to load the files in the order you need to define the default site first and they are loaded according to the directory alphabetical order.

Always according to the same Apache doc (following examples link in the page), if you use `_default_` vhost, it must be defined before other vhosts and that's exactly what you will be doing defining the vhost in the order you want but when using `_default_` vhost, the main server will not respond anymore to requests.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to keep the vhost names like they are as they use a pretty structured format. Also I find the file naming workaround a bit clumsy as the knowledge about default vhost/file naming is implicit (as opposed to an apache directive which I can google/document).

Comment: @FelixSchwarz The first `<VirtualHost>` to load that matches your `NameVirtualHost` directive will be default.  There is no way whatsoever to change this using directives or the `_default_` address declaration (which will only serve to render that vhost completely inactive).

Comment: @FelixSchwarz, you don't need to change the vhost name, only the name of the file containing the vhost definition (or only the name of the slink that goes in .../apache2/sites-enabled directory.). The vhost files are loaded following the order they appear in .../sites-enabled directory

Comment: updated answer with documentation link from Apache Docs